# MaterializeCSS dropdown menu going upward

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I'm using dropdown menu from MaterializeCSS http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html but I want that menu to open upward not downward. Can I do this via options or I will have to change some stuff direct in the framework?  I tried to use gutter in options and other options and it does not work.

Comment: Enter the specific (HTML/CSS) parts here and we might be able to help you modifiy it. I don't want to sound harsh, but we don't like to follow links, read the docs there and try to post back here. We are willing to help, but the base work in posting a good question has to be done by yourself.

Comment: Yes of course - I do apologize for that but I had to go to meeting. I will do that in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

This may solve your problem.

set it true like this **belowOrigin: true,** // Displays dropdown below the button

`$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        constrainWidth: false,
        gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
        belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
        alignment: 'left', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left 
        stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
      }
    );`

Comment: The question is asking how to make the dropdown appear above the trigger.

Comment: belowOrigin doesn't appear in the documentation. Is this a undocumented feature?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this style:

```
.autocomplete-content {
    top: 46px !important;
    max-height: 300px !important;
}
```

This keeps autocomplete below

To me this works very well

Comment: The question is asking how to make the dropdown appear above the trigger. Also while your CSS could be modified to suit the question, the answer isn't specific to MaterializeCSS or dropdown menus.