# MaterializeCSS Autocomplete going upward

Tags: javascript, materialize

The Materialize CSS Autocomplete opens in the upward position when at the lower end of the screen and it has a larger list to display, the problem is that the text input area with the blinking cursor gets covered and the user doesn't get the idea that he can type.

1) How can you force it to always go downwards? or, 2) How can you tell it to open above the input area without covering it when it decides to open in the upwards position? Ether of these solutions would be OK.

The closest solution I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746509) (for the dropdown menu) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701816), however these solutions look to me like jQuery which I am not familiar with (yet) and would need a plain JavaScript solution.

I use MaterializeCSS version 1.0.0 through the CDN.

Pictures: [Autocomplete Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm3B4.png) and [Autocomplete Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCjP5.png)

Comment: Hi! How are you initializing the component? Are you able to declare an `options` variable that can set things like `belowOrigin`?

Comment: Can you show a picture of that?

Comment: @Damon `belowOrigin` seems to have no effect, see the autocomplete at the bottom of my JS Bin [link](https://jsbin.com/segehizuyu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke I added links to pics on the bottom of the post.

Comment: can you provide a code

Comment: @SalunkeAkash Here is a working example with code [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/doravitisa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi the autocomplete is going upward because there is not space below but use can try this code

```
<style>

        #autocomplete-options-509040f2-ba4c-72d4-413d-2e375f5c25f8
        {
             position: initial;

        }
      </style>
```

or you can add jquery to add height of the parent div when the auto complete has been click

```
$("#idofautocomplte").on("click", function () {
        $("#parentDivId").css("height", "400px"); 
    });
```

Comment: The CSS solution did not work for me, is the ID always `autocomplete-options-509040f2-ba4c-72d4-413d-2e375f5c25f8` or is that generated dynamically?

Comment: it is based on your snippet you have to check in your original code so you can use either id or class its is logic so you can solve your problem with this

Comment: jquery is not an option for me I am not familiar with it. (I also assume that jquery  would add more resources to the page at load time, which I would anyway not want to do)

Comment: [new Link](https://jsbin.com/bucimorevo/1/edit?html,css,js,output) I tried doing it with the class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see what @SalunkeAkash is suggesting. Try `.autocomplete-content {
    position: initial;
}` in your `.css` file. It'll make the drop-down push the screen "up" so it will be visible as you type. It looks like it renders "up" when all options are showing, but "down" as you type.

Answer (score 0):

try use this style:

```
    .autocomplete-content{
    top: 46px !important;
    max-height: 300px !important;
}
```

this keep autocomplete always downward
To me it is working very well